# hello can I use shared preferences to my on boarding screens and make them only appear once but without making them the first pages to my app?

Tags: flutter, dart

flutter shared perferences all tutorials on this topic is for pages starting with on boarding screens..

I tried it with the same way but it has failed

Comment: Add your code snippet in your post. So that people get better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SharedPref.init;
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: StackOverFlowProblem(),
    ),
  );
}



class StackOverFlowProblem extends StatefulWidget {
  const StackOverFlowProblem({super.key});

  @override
  State<StackOverFlowProblem> createState() => _StackOverFlowProblemState();
}

class _StackOverFlowProblemState extends State<StackOverFlowProblem> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      SharedPref.getIsClosed == true
          ? Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const HomePage(),
              ),
            )
          : Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const OnBoarding1(),
              ),
            );
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Image(
              image: NetworkImage(
                  'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQxb8wmqzkCW1ecie9m2yA_bRmmZ9wzxzwLhQ&usqp=CAU')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OnBoarding1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const OnBoarding1({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'On Boarding Screen 1',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 500,
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const OnBoarding2(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: const Text('Next'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OnBoarding2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const OnBoarding2({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'On Boarding Screen 2',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 500,
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const OnBoarding3(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: const Text('Next'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OnBoarding3 extends StatelessWidget {
  const OnBoarding3({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'On Boarding Screen 3',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 500,
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  SharedPref.setIsClosed = true;
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const HomePage(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: const Text('Next'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Home Page',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SharedPref {
  static SharedPreferences? pref;
  static Future<SharedPreferences> get init async =>
      pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  static set setIsClosed(bool closed) =>
      pref!.setBool(SharedKey.isClosed, closed);

  static bool? get getIsClosed => pref!.getBool(SharedKey.isClosed);
}

class SharedKey {
  static const isClosed = 'isClosed';
}
```